# printing out specific letters from a text document to reveal a message?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that will extract letters from a text document, and append those letters in a list that will be printed out to reveal a message. It's giving me an invalid syntax, but I don't know how else to write it.

Here is what I have so far

```
def decodefile():
        codeKey = [[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 14], [5], [1, 16], [7,8], [14,18]]
        decoded = []
        with open("sentences.txt") as fr:
            listLine = [ch for ch in line]
            for x in range(0, len(listLine)
                if (x.index in codeKey):
                    decoded.append(x)
                    print(decoded)

decodefile()
```

Here is the text if it matters:

They like apples.

I enjoy pears.

Time for breakfast.

Serve the oatmeal please.

Leave a tip for the waiter.

Comment: Next time post the error message too. Close the parentheses at the end of `for` and add a colon (`:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the obvious missing parenthesis in in front of the for loop, you were also missing a few more things.

```
def decodefile():
        codeKey = [[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 14], [5], [1, 16], [7,8], [14,18]]
        decoded = []
        with open("sentences.txt") as fr:
            # Keep track of which line you are on
            line_no = 0
            # Iterate over each line in the file
            for line in fr:
                listLine = [ch for ch in line]
                for x in range(0, len(listLine)):
                    # check the appropriate code key, not the whole list
                    if (x in codeKey[line_no]):
                        decoded.append(listLine[x])
                        print(decoded)
                # Move to the next line
                line_no +=1

decodefile()
```

This results in the following output:

```
['T']
['T', 'h']
['T', 'h', 'e']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i', 's']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i', 's', 'h']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i', 's', 'h', 'e']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i', 's', 'h', 'e', 'r']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'k', 'e', 'o', 'i', 's', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e']
```

You can also add `''.join(decoded)` at the end that joins this into a single string which would give:

```
The keoishere
```